# How to use group by and ordery by with some operation in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two columns price and sold_count for the product table. How do write sql query to find the top 3 shops having highest Revenue (calculate revenue as price*sold_count).

I have following table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` shop, `order by` the `sum()` of revenues for each group and `limit` to 3:

```
select shop 
from yourtable
group by shop
order by sum(price * sold_count) desc
limit 3;
```